# MVC 4 $Ajax JSON Request returns status 0, statusText: "error"

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying update a value on my page every 5 seconds using jQuery $.ajax, this code used to work fine, but after deployment to production server it appears to be randomly failing. On some pages it will work, and on others if fails with the error: status 0, statusText: "error".

Can anyone spot any errors misnomers in the code / markup?

I use this to call my method every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function () {
            updateMessages();
}, 5000);
```

updateMessages looks like this:

```
function updateMessages() {
    $.ajax({
       beforeSend: function () { },
       complete: function () { },
       type: "GET",
       url: '@Url.Action("GetUnreadMessagesJson", "Message", new { Area = "" })',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
           var newUnreadMessages = result.UnreadMsgCount;
       },
       error: function (rsult) {
           console.log(rsult);
       }
   });
}
```

My server code (Action) inside the MVC Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetUnreadMessagesJson() {

   int unreadMessages = 0;
   try {
       unreadMessages = messageService.GetUnreadMessageCount(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
   }
   catch (Exception) {
       throw;
   }
   return Json(new {
       UnreadMsgCount = unreadMessages
       //,UnreadMessages = unreadMessages
   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I use Fiddler2 to analyse the request on my local machine I see this in the response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 17:38:50 GMT
>   Content-Length: 20

{"UnreadMsgCount":3}

Which looks good and is what I expect, but I never see this request when the site is live. Fiddler2 never shows any outgoing Ajax request, Google Chrome's Console shows:

> Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

Which has status:0 and statusText: "error" inside. Nothing more.

How on earth do I go about investigating this issue if there is nothing wrong with my code? Has anyone seen this before?

**EDIT**

After testing this issue with several browsers including IE, Firefox and Safari it appears that the issue is only limited to Google Chrome. I have submitted a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=266483) and will update this post with any response I get.

Thanks,

Comment: I should also add on the live site I have a filter to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. I have temporarily disabled this, but it doesn't appear to affect the results.

Comment: is there any difference in rendered URL? @Url.Action("GetUnreadMessagesJson", "Message", new { Area = "" })

Comment: @Nenad no, when viewing source in my browser I see: url: '/Message/GetUnreadMessagesJson' - which I have copied and pasted into the browser address bar like so: www.domain.com/Message/GetUnreadMessagesJson - I get the result I expect - A JSON Array containing "UnreadMsgCount"

Comment: It's object, not array. Anyway, code looks fine. How about your messageService throwing exception on live? Did you check that?

Comment: @Nenad I placed logs inside the GetUnreadMessagesJson() action, it never enters the method via JS, but when I enter the URL into the browser, the logs get executed and no errors are thrown.

Comment: It just occured to me that I can use a browser other than Google Chrome. The error doesn't appear to be happening in Firefox or IE!

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set text/json as follows

```
 return Json(new {
   UnreadMsgCount = unreadMessages
   //,UnreadMessages = unreadMessages
 }, 
 "text/json",
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that when a subsequent call is made it is cancelling the previous call, making it return with the status of 0. This could explain why you see it on occasion as if the previous call completes before then next is sent off then you won't experience the problem, so anything slowing down the calls could make the issue arise.

Based on your question I take it you don't want to abort previous calls so one option would be to make the calls synchronous, so that if one is in progress don't send off another. You'll want to hold onto a reference to the ajax call and if it's not complete then don't send off another. Something like:

```
    var updateCall;

    function updateMessages() {
        if (updateCall && updateCall.readystate != 4){
            updateCall = $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () { },
                complete: function () { },
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUnreadMessagesJson", "Message", new { Area = "" })',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var newUnreadMessages = result.UnreadMsgCount;
                },
                error: function (rsult) {
                    console.log(rsult);
                }
           });
        }
    }
```